# Is it necessary to do SQLite local querys in an Asyntask?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a doubt... I want to execute this code, but I don't know if it's better to do it in an Asynctask or it isn't necessary and I can execute it in the main function.. What do you think?

The SQLite Database is local, so the acces is so fast.. Thank you!

```
/*Here I create an object of SQLiteHelper Class*/
        SQLiteHelper bbDD;
        bbDD = new SQLiteHelper(getActivity()); 

/* Calling this method I open the database connection */
        bbDD.open(); 

/* This method returns me an ArrayList, doing a SELECT in the SQLite Local Database*/
        arrayList = bbDD.selectAll(); 

/* Here I Close the database connection */
        bbDD.close();
```

Comment: Why you need this to be done in Asynctask?

Answer (score 1):

Today's devices are fast enough to handle SQLite query inside main UI thread, but when you try to query big size of data inside SQLite (for example if you have more than hundred rows of data inside that database (Especially if row contains base64 encoded image strings)) user can see some UI lag, that's why  query in Asynctask makes UI faster - without lags. If you don't have big data inside SQLite, there is no need to use AsyncTask for query.

Answer (score 0):

No dude there is no need to write SQLite local querys in an Asyntask.

Comment: And it's for sure that it will never reach the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depend on the **size** of your database.

I have experienced to select hundreds of rows, with lot of columns on SQLite. It does not make the apps very lag, but it does make the apps a **little bit lag** (and **my client can feel this**). So, i moved the `select` operation to the `onBackground` in the `Async` class, and the apps run flawlessly again.

If you only have a little data, theres no need to put it on the background.